# Which form does Casein take in milk (before and after extraction)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

In [this video](https://youtu.be/BV8aFRII1M4), NileRed said

> `casein` is exists in milk as a salt `Calcium caseinate`. And that structure of the salt is composed of 3 forms of `casein`. `Alpha`, `beta`, `kappa`. Together they form a stable structure called a `micelle`.

Further on he said that the kappa's polar part is bonding with the water and the non polar is bonding with the alpha and beta parts.

Then he showed that the sub-micelles are tied together with `calcium phosphate`.

My question is :

**1- does casein actually exists in milk as a salt `Calcium caseinate`?**
Because in [this site](https://www.livestrong.com/article/509796-what-is-calcium-caseinate/) they said :

> Calcium caseinate is produce by changing the pH of milk to neutral or acid. In this state, casein becomes insoluble in water... . After separation, manufacturers combine casein with calcium hydroxide at high alkaline levels and dry the protein.

Which shows that Calcium caseinate is a product not the input. or they just re-produced Calcium caseinate again?

[image]

The second confusion is
**2- Is the calcium that is tying the sub-micelle together the same that is mentioned in the name `Calcium caseinate`?**

1. If YES, then by breaking the bond, do we just end up with pure casein? And why isn't the phosphate present in the name?
2. If NO, then which one did we break from?

[image]

Comment: Is "Nile Red", a good replacement of authentic books or published references? Many dot.com type websites without an author are dubious. Why should we trust "Live Strong"? Try searching your question in Google Scholar. I upvote because you made an effort to search elsewhere besides "Nile Red".

Comment: Please check the title question. Its meaning seems unreadable, to me.

Comment: @M.Farooq , I totally agree with your point. it's not like "Nile Red" is better than authentic books but he is better than me. that's why I'm asking other people who are also better than me. that being said, I'll check google scholar. thanks!

Comment: @Alchimista , oh my bad dude. i've no idea how I messed up the title this way. it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/calcium-caseinate) they said :

> Caseins form complex particles or micelles, which are usually complexes of ***calcium caseinate and calcium phosphate***. When milk clots or curdles as a result of heat, pH changes, or enzymes, the casein is transformed into an insoluble ***caseinate-calcium phosphate*** complex.

Which means :

1. Yes, in milk, it exists in calcium caseinate form
2. No, There are 2 different calcium in the formula
3. We broke the Calcium caseinate NOT calcium phosphate